# QML XmlListModel messes sorting when delegated

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to get a `Canvas` to draw lines in the same order as presented in this xml-file:

```
<root>
<doc><nopeus>80.0</nopeus><aika>40.0</aika></doc>
<doc><nopeus>110.0</nopeus><aika>80.0</aika></doc>
<doc><nopeus>120.0</nopeus><aika>120.0</aika></doc>
<doc><nopeus>190.0</nopeus><aika>160.0</aika></doc><doc><nopeus>243.0</nopeus><aika>200.0</aika></doc><doc><nopeus>260.0</nopeus><aika>240.0</aika></doc><doc><nopeus>300.0</nopeus><aika>280.0</aika></doc><doc><nopeus>350.0</nopeus><aika>320.0</aika></doc>
</root>
```

QML-file with XmlListModel:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Page {
    id: page
    property alias startx : coords.mX
    property alias starty : coords.mY

    Item {
        id: coords
        property int mX: 0
        property int mY: 0
    }

    XmlListModel {
        id: myxml
        source: "/home/nemo/filename.xml"
        query: "/root/doc"
        XmlRole { name: "nopeus"; query: "nopeus/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "aika"; query: "aika/string()" }
    }

    ListView {
        model: myxml
        anchors.fill: page
        delegate:
            Item {
                Chart {
                    xc: coords.mX;
                    yc: coords.mY;
                    xd: aika;
                    yd: nopeus;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Chart.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: myrect
    width: 540
    height: 960
    color: "transparent"

    property int xd: 0
    property int yd: 0
    property int xc: 0
    property int yc: 0

    Canvas {
        id: mycanvas
        width: myrect.width; height: myrect.height;
        onPaint: {
                var context = getContext('2d')
                context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000"
                context.lineWidth = 2
                context.beginPath()
                context.moveTo(xc,yc)
                context.lineTo(xd,yd)
                context.stroke()
                startx = xd
                starty = yd              
         }
    }
}
```

The question is why is the resulting path messed up when inserted in the `ListView` via delegates? I have tried to sort the path items separately, via a function and another `ListModel` but the result is the same.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are created for *each* item in a model. Your model contains **eight** items (as of your input). Hence, you create **eight** `Canvas`es (each one as a `ListView` item, i.e. at (theoretical) increasing `y` w.r.t. `ListView` origin coordinates).

Combile these problems with the (probably wrongly set) starting points...and you get a random mess! You can't see that, since the `Canvas`es tend to overlap due to sizing/constraints set on the component.

In this case you just need **one** `Canvas` on which each `myxml` item is painted. Here is a (naive) adaptation of your code which correctly shows the path stored in the xml file:

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    XmlListModel {
        id: myxml
        source: "qrc:/filename.xml"   // added to the resources
        query: "/root/doc"
        XmlRole { name: "nopeus"; query: "nopeus/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "aika"; query: "aika/string()" }
        onStatusChanged: {
            if(status === XmlListModel.Ready)
                comp.mod = myxml    // set the model ASA it is ready to be used
        }
    }

    Chart {
        id: comp
        anchors.fill: parent
        mod: myxml
    }
}

// Chart.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Item {
    property var mod: undefined

    onModChanged: {
        if(mod)
            mycanvas.requestPaint()   // repaint only when the model is available
    }

    Canvas {
        id: mycanvas
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height;
        onPaint: {
            var context = getContext('2d')
            context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000"
            context.lineWidth = 2
            context.beginPath()
            context.moveTo(0,0)
            // iterate over all the point to print them
            for(var i = 0; i < mod.count; i++)
            {
                var point = mod.get(i)
                context.lineTo(point.aika, point.nopeus)
            }
            context.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting path rendered:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quick and exact answer!